# Pass Information from NestJS middlewares to controllers/services

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I have applied authentication in NestJS middlewares and decoding all the information from user token by the third party API.

Now I have got the information in my middleware, how can I send that information to controllers and services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal for middlewares to add information to the `request` object (eg. adding a user object).

For a clean way to extract information from the request object and inject it into the controller you can make a [custom route decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#custom-route-decorators)

For example, extracting the user:

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const User = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

And then in your controller

```js
@Get()
async findOne(@User() user: UserEntity) {
  console.log(user);
}
```

From there you can just ensure that your service methods receive the User as a regular method parameter

Comment: So, if I am using a guard, and it autorizes the requesting user, I can add some metadata on to the request object and then return true from the guard?